# Magento 2 : Add header and Footer in Checkout custom theme

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, layout

I need to add header and footer on checkout page. i have try below code for this but its not working its display only Logo on Header i want to add full header with menu and top links.

```
app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/base/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml
```

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
</body>
```

Comment: __checkout_index_index.xml__ should be at `app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index`

Comment: I have already try this

Comment: let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ajay Patel Try this

Create checkout_index_index.xml at

> app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
        <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="content" before="-"/>
        <move element="minicart" destination="header-wrapper"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now flush cache and try...!

Comment: ok let me check with this

Comment: yes its working but in mobile store menu not found any idea?

Comment: can you please check this?

Comment: store.menu  this not generated using this code