# Magento2 Add header and footer in checkout page in enterprise edition

Tags: magento2, checkout, theme, header, checkout-page

Can anyone let me know how to add header and footer in checkout page in magento2? i have Magento Enterprise edition, i tried with below code in theme/checkout_index_index.xml but its not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper" before="-" />
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
        <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below existing page where solution was given.

[Magento 2 : Add header and Footer in Checkout custom theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193540/magento-2-add-header-and-footer-in-checkout-custom-theme)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, i tried with above solution but header part displaying twice and with smaller width
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/6636050?key=8ed1516358e8797da66d1a5adbeb39e9

Answer (score 0):

I added following in checkout_index_index.xml and it worked:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
             <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
             <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />     
             <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
             <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" /> 
             <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
             <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
 </body>
 </page>
```

**NOTE:** layout="1column" is most important thing to be replaced